# cgMiner Auto-Start on Raspbian

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to make cgMiner auto-start when my Raspberry Pi (Raspbian Linux) starts.

Edited the rc.local file:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

and added this line:

```
nohup ./cgminer-3.1.1/cgminer --config /home/pi/cgminer.conf -S /dev/ttyUSB0 -S /dev/ttyUSB1 >/dev/null 2>&1&
```

and cgMiner doesn't start. If I type in terminal the exact same line with sudo in front it works perfectly.

```
sudo nohup ./cgminer-3.1.1/cgminer --config /home/pi/cgminer.conf -S /dev/ttyUSB0 -S /dev/ttyUSB1 >/dev/null 2>&1&
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is related to the path or better the current working directory.

You are using ./cgminer and not a full path. So either use the full path or first cd to the directory containing the cgminer program.

Also have a look at the following page over at adafruit doing the exact same thing you are trying to accomplish

http://learn.adafruit.com/piminer-raspberry-pi-bitcoin-miner/configure-auto-start

Adafruit has the following code in `/etc/rc.local`

```
cd /home/pi/PiMiner
python PiMiner.py &
cd ..
nohup ./cgminer-3.1.1/cgminer --config /home/pi/cgminer.conf -S /dev/ttyUSB0 -S /dev/ttyUSB1 >/dev/null 2>&1&
```

The first and third line (the cd commands) ensure that the folder containing the folder containing the cgminer command is the current directory.

From the two cd commands adding the following command before the line containing the cgminer command would solve your issue

```
cd /home/pi
```

Comment: As you can see in my description, the information posted on AdaFruit is exactly what I've tried and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the solution for this problem, assuming it is the same as for bfgminer.
After spending a full day playing with init.d scripts, I found the simplest way is to make sure your cgminier.conf file has all the arguments in then add the following to the end of /etc/rc.local

cd /home/YOURNAME/bfgminer
sudo ./bfgminer

It ran without the sudo part, but didn't start up my block erupter without it.

I also managed to get it running from init.d, but had issues with it preventing system rebooting when done that way.

Hope that helps